# Best way of updating single record with new order number for multiple records in EF Core 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Wonder if anyone can shed some light on this: I have list of records and want to set new order/index number beside each record. Using EF Core 7 and was looking at `ExecuteUpdateAsync` issue with the code below is

> Translation of method 'System.Collections.Generic.List.IndexOf' failed.

Code:

```
public async Task Execute(List<int> listOfIdsInNewOrder)
{     
    await _db.fakeTable
             .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s => s.SetProperty(e => e.ItemOrder, 
                                      e => listOfIdsInNewOrder.IndexOf(e.Id) + 1));
}
```

What is the best way of updating multiple records with a new itemorder value or is back to using a loop and updating each record individually?

Comment: EF Core is an ORM. It translates expressions to SQL, it doesn't execute C# code in the database. You need to pass an expression that can be translated and `IndexOf` can't. SQL Server doesn't even have array types

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, yes indexof was just example, main question is what best way of updating multiple records with different order numbers and if it was possible with new ExecuteUpdateAsync. :-)

Comment: In that case the question is unclear. Why use EF at all? You aren't dealing with *objects* any more. EF isn't a database driver. The number of items matters too. How you do it depends *heavily* on specific database features, eg the availability of array  or table parameter types, JSON or XML, and the number of items. Performance depends on indexing and parameter values have no indexes

Comment: Where does `listOfIdsInNewOrder` come from? You may be able to write a different query that increments the results of the original query, eg `UPDATE Items Set ItemOrder=ItemOrder+1 Where CategoryID=@category and ID!=@topId`.

Comment: You can't do that in *best* way with EF Core. Better load records and change their properties, then `SaveChangesAsync`

Comment: `ExecuteUpdate` always generates one simple UPDATE statement in SQL. What you want can't be expressed in one such statement.

Comment: Cheers for that everyone, tho was worth asking :-)